Initialize struct with embedding
package main

import "fmt"

type (
    Step struct {
        Type string
    }
    prompt struct {
        Step
    }
)

func main() {
    p := prompt{Step:Step{Type: "test1"}}
    fmt.Println(p.Type)
    var q prompt
    q.Type = "test2"
    fmt.Println(q.Type)
    r := prompt{
        Type: "test3",
    }
    _ = r
}

In the code above, Type: "test3" will trigger a compilation error.  My question is, why I can do q.Type = "test2" while Type is an embedded (indirect) field of prompt, yet the "direct assignment" fails to compile?
Go version go1.23.3 linux/amd64

q.Type is a shorthand for q.Step.Type. When you initialize your struct, you don't refer to q.Type, you refer to prompt.Step and Step.Type. When you use a composite literal of prompt, you have to provide a value for its Step field, and not a value of the Type field (of Step).
